May we conclude something about a congruence class that $\mathrm{gnu}(2048)$ lies in?
Denote $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ as the number of groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism.
$\mathrm{gnu}(2048)$ is the smallest unknown value of $\mathrm{gnu}$ as of 2024. But, I'm wondering if something of the form $$\mathrm{gnu}(2048) \equiv a \mod n$$ is known for some $n > 1$.
I'm certainly no expert here, so I could be completely wrong, but I was originally wondering about the parity of this number and wondering if that may be known. I know that there is some sort of inductive process where, if all the groups of order $2^{k-1}$ are known, we may find the number of groups of order $2^{k}$ via some algorithm. That's how we know $\mathrm{gnu}(1024)=49487367289$. But note that it was originally incorrectly calculated that $\mathrm{gnu}(1024)=49487365422$ (see here), which was only noticed in 2021, with the $\mathrm{gnu}(1024)=49487365422$ result calculated much earlier. So, I imagine we don't know much about these numbers $\mod 2$, as otherwise that mistake would have been spotted immediately.
Perhaps that has since changed, or perhaps we know something for some other $n$? Or is this something we just know nothing about for now?

What reason could there be for expecting such a relationship?

If there were such an inductive process , gnu(2048) would surely be known even if this step would be a "big step". But this is not the case. It is notoriously difficult to find gnu-values in general , in particular if large exponents in the prime factorization occur. We can find tight lower bounds for gnu(2048) however. So the magnitude is actually known , but not yet the concrete value.
